# Methods in Windows Service not working as Timer events

Tags: c#, timer, windows-services

I'm creating this simple windows service to play a beep every six seconds. When I Start it on Debug Mode, it simply stops right after the start. There seem to be no errors or exceptions.

```
 public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
        static Timer myTimer;
        public Service1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void OnDebug() 
        { 
            OnStart( null );
        }

        protected override void OnStart( string[] args )
        {

            myTimer = new Timer();
            myTimer.AutoReset = true;
            myTimer.Interval = 60000;
            myTimer.Enabled = true;
            myTimer.Start();

            myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler( OnTimedEvent );

        }

        private static void OnTimedEvent( object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e )
        {
                SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
        }


    }
```

My main method

```
static void Main()
{
#if DEBUG
    Service1 testService = new Service1();
    testService.OnDebug();

#else
    ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
    ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
    {
        new Service1()
    };
    ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
#endif
}
```

The beep works fine on itself. But it doesn't work with a timer.

Comment: Can you show your Main method?

Comment: `myTimer.Interval = 60000;` that's sixty seconds, not six.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep on running your service, you can add this code after line `testService.OnDebug();`. It will make your service run until you press q.

```
Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
while (Console.Read() != 'q') ;
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked fine. Also, I changed the output mode to `Console Application`